# Eager loading with conditional - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this query:

```
 $tournament = Tournament::with(
            'championships',
            'championships.settings',
            'championships.category',
            'championships.tree.users',
        )->first();
```

Right now, it gives me the tournament with all attached championships.

What I need is to get the tournament but only with the championship which match the `$request->championshipId` that I have.

Off course, I also want this filter in all the other relations `('championships.settings', 'championships.category','championships.tree.users')`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use [`Constraining Eager Loading`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) like this:

```
$tournaments = Tournament::with(['championships' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('something', 'like', '%this%');
},
'championships.settings' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('something', 'like', '%this%');
},
...])->get();
```

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro - If this helps you to get your correct answer then please accept & upvote this answer... This motivates me to answer other questions like this :D and helps community to get best answer quickly...

Answer (score 11):

Load the relations in the subquery constraint:

```
$tournament = Tournament::with(['championships' => function($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('id', $request->championshipId)
        ->with([
            'settings',
            'category',
            'tree.users'
        ]);
}])->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way of doing this,
first grab data.

```
$user = User::all();
```

then add the condition to load relation

```
if(condition){

     $user->load('profile')
}
```

Or you can use ***WHEN*** to conditionally load the relational data.

```
$doctors = new Doctor();

    $doctors->with( 'subSpeciality' )
            ->when( $searchKey, function ( $query ) use ( $searchKey ) {
               return $query->where( 'name', 'like', "%$searchKey%" )
                            ->orwhere( 'code', 'like', "%$searchKey%" )
                            ->orwhere( 'sfdc_code','like',"%$searchKey%" );
            } );
```