# How to modify array structure returned by eloquent in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I currently have the below array structure that I get when running Bonus::with('users')->get()

I have tried adding the array and merging similar keys but it is not working. I tried using the helper methods provided in laravel but I don't seem to be able to get it working.

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"users_id": 1,
"bonus_type_id": 1,
"is_paid": 0,
"amount": "100.00",
"description": "desc",
"note": null,
"created_by": 2,
"last_modified_by": null,
"created_at": null,
"updated_at": null,
"deleted_at": null,
"user": {
"id": 1,
"name": "test",
"email": "test@testing.com",
"email_verified_at": null,
"status": 1,
"created_at": "2019-07-18 11:41:35",
"updated_at": "2019-07-18 11:41:35",
"deleted_at": null
}
},
{
"id": 2,
"users_id": 1,
"bonus_type_id": 2,
"is_paid": 0,
"amount": "100.00",
"description": "desc",
"note": null,
"created_by": 2,
"last_modified_by": null,
"created_at": null,
"updated_at": null,
"deleted_at": null,
"user": {
"id": 1,
"name": "test",
"email": "test@testing.com",
"email_verified_at": null,
"status": 1,
"created_at": "2019-07-18 11:41:35",
"updated_at": "2019-07-18 11:41:35",
"deleted_at": null
}
},
{
"id": 3,
"users_id": 2,
"bonus_type_id": 2,
"is_paid": 1,
"amount": "100.00",
"description": "desc",
"note": null,
"created_by": 2,
"last_modified_by": null,
"created_at": null,
"updated_at": null,
"deleted_at": null,
"user": {
"id": 1,
"name": "another test",
"email": "another@testing.com",
"email_verified_at": null,
"status": 1,
"created_at": "2019-07-18 11:41:35",
"updated_at": "2019-07-18 11:41:35",
"deleted_at": null
}
}
]
```

I want the result to be something like that

```
[
  {
    user_id: 1,
    name: "test",
    bonuses: [
      {
        bonus_type_id: 1,
        amount: 100,
        is_paid: 0,
      },
      {
        bonus_type_id: 2,
        amount: 100,
        is_paid: 0,
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    user_id: 2,
    name: "another",
    bonuses: [
      {
        bonus_type_id: 2,
        amount: 100,
        is_paid: 1,
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: How will I be able to return a different json response using collections maybe

Comment: Take a look at the fractal package: https://fractal.thephpleague.com/

Comment: Is it possible to rely on Laravel methods only to change the response?

Comment: please try `User::with('bonuses')->get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your eloquent relationship. Define `hasMany` relationship function `bonuses` inside `User` model for bonuses table and use that to get the desired result like so:

```
User::with('bonuses')->get();
```

That way it will return results from users table and populate bonuses for each user.

makes sense?

Comment: This does make sense! I think I missed that one! I will try it and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: You have users_id key instead of user_id, define it explicitely as a second paramter when defining the relation so that script knows what foreign key to target

Comment: Is it possible to only show the users that have a bonus? using eloquent

Comment: Yes , you can eager load with condition. Look this thread up..it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533776/eager-loading-with-conditional-laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can get specific information with select subquery, if your relations are correctly set, this should work.

```
User::select('user_id','name','bonus_id')
    ->with(array('bonuses'=> function($query){
         $query->select('bonus_type_id','amount','is_paid');
    }))->get();
```